# Share content of a container with another on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, docker-volume

here is what i'm trying to achieve :

I have two containers sharing a volume, my first one is a php container, it constains all the file from my project (html, js, whatoever)

The second one is a front end server, say apache

Previously I was sharing a volume in my docker compose and all was fine, my apache can see the file from the php container.

Now I'm using kubernetes, I tried to define a shared volume, and it's actually ok but the fact is I lost all my data from php container. I'm actually sharing a volume, if i touch a new file in it, i can see it from the other container. But it seems my initial files (from the php container) aren't there any more

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ms
spec:
  restartPolicy: Always
  volumes:
    - name: test-pierre-container-vol
  containers:
  - name: test-ms-php
    image: myappphp:dev
    env:
      - name: DATABASE_URL
        value: "mysql://root:root@mysql:3306/azert"
      - name: APP_ENV
        value: "PROD"
    volumeMounts:
    - name: test-pierre-container-vol
      mountPath: "/var/www/test"
  - name: test-ms-apache
    image: myappapache:dev
    volumeMounts:
    - name: test-pierre-container-vol
      mountPath: "/var/www/html"
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-ms-php
  labels:
    run: my-ms-php
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8099
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
```

any idea / advice ?

Comment: Can you share both deployments and your volume claim manifests?

Comment: @cookiedough here you go but no volume claim as we don't want a persistant volume

Comment: That's obviously because you used emptyDir volume. Why you use emptyDir? It will be wiped out every time you restart pod. Try at least hostPath volume.

Comment: my bad, I'm not using emptyDir, it was for a test purpose

Comment: but then what volume are you using? Configuration you provided is not valid because you did not specify volume source.

Comment: @VasilyAngapov I'm pretty new to k8s, I thought I didn't need to provide any source as I just want a temp volume that will desapear when pod goes down

Comment: I think hostPath volume is what you need. EmptyDir volume will always be empty at pod start. Read more: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath